# Passing values in 2 strings and removing them from a .txt file

Tags: java, string

I have an issue where I'm passing 2 values (Facebook username and Facebook password) in 2 strings and then removing them from a .txt file.

This is my code:

```
private static String[] fbuser;
private static String[] fbpass;
FileReader fr;
BufferedReader br;
PrintWriter pw;     
String tmp;
int FileContentCount;
int noOfUsers = 3;

public void insertFacebookDetails() throws InterruptedException {

    fbuser = new String[noOfUsers];
    fbpass = new String[noOfUsers];

    String UserFileName = "fbusers.txt";

    try {           
        fr = new FileReader(UserFileName);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        FileContentCount = 0;

        while ((tmp = br.readLine()) != null) {             
            fbuser[FileContentCount] = tmp;
            tmp = br.readLine();
            fbpass[FileContentCount] = tmp;
            FileContentCount++;             
        }
        br.close();
        fr.close();
        System.out.println(fbuser[0] + ": " + fbpass[0]);

        pw = new PrintWriter(UserFileName);
        int count = 1;
        while (count < FileContentCount) {
            pw.write(fbuser[count] + "\n");
            pw.write(fbpass[count] + "\n");
            count++;
        }
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }       
    for (String fbLogin : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(fbLogin);  
    }
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(EMAIL)));           
    driver.findElement(By.id(EMAIL)).sendKeys(fbuser);
    driver.findElement(By.id(PASSWORD)).sendKeys(fbpass);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.name(LOGIN)).click(); 
}
```

I have the users in the .txt file in this order:

- fb_user1
- fb_pass1
- fb_user2
- fb_pass2
- fb_user3
- fb_pass3
- fb_user4 etc etc

When it finds the email id it actually sends 3 users (since the noOfUsers value is 3), but if I put a number lower than that, it won't work. (getting an arrayoutofbounds error)

The second problem is that it doesn't delete the users from the .txt file.

I also don't know where to put the following code:

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(EMAIL)));           
driver.findElement(By.id(EMAIL)).sendKeys(fbuser);
driver.findElement(By.id(PASSWORD)).sendKeys(fbpass);
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.name(LOGIN)).click();
```

I know it needs to be somewhere after it reads it and before it deletes it. I tried all the ways possible I know but I'm baffled.

Can anyone help me please?

EDIT:
This is how the code looks in an abstract class

```
public static void readFile() {
     try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))){
          String tmp;
          while((tmp = reader.readLine())!= null){
            fbUsers.add(tmp);
            System.out.println(tmp);
          }
          System.out.println(fbUsers.size());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
}

public static void writeFile() {
    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName))){
          for(String fbUser : fbUsers){
            writer.write(fbUser);
            writer.newLine();
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void insertFacebookDetails(String fbUser) throws InterruptedException {  
    readFile();
    for (String fbLogin : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(fbLogin);  
    }
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(EMAIL)));   
    String username = fbUser.split("/")[0];
    String password = fbUser.split("/")[1];
    fbUsers.remove(fbUser);
    driver.findElement(By.id(EMAIL)).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.id(PASSWORD)).sendKeys(password);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.name(LOGIN)).click(); 
    writeFile();
}
```

This is where I'm calling the method in another class:

```
public void step1() {
   insertFacebookDetails(fbUsers.get(0));
}
```

Comment: One problem at a time: which users do you want to delete and under what conditions?

Comment: So I want to get the first user and first password (first 2 lines) from the .txt file, insert them in the fields on the Facebook login form, and then delete them.

Comment: Do you need to save it in each line, or can you save it also like this: fb_user1/fb_pass1?

Comment: @Morchul: not necessarily, I just want it to make it work :)

Comment: @Morchul: the thing is, if I want to store hundreds of accounts, it's kind of hard to do it on only one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a example how you can read the users from file and delete the one from file you login:
First the users are stored like this in the `fbusers.txt` file:

> fb_user1/fb_pass1
>  fb_user2/fb_pass2
>  fb_user3/fb_pass3
>   etc...

Then instead of `String[]` we use `List<String>` because it's expand automatically. So we don't get an arrayOutOfBounds exception by adding fbUsers to it.

First we read all fbUsers from our file:

```
public static void readFile(){
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))){
      String tmp;
      while((tmp = reader.readLine())!= null){
        fbUsers.add(tmp);
        System.out.println(tmp);
      }
    } catch (IOException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

So now all fbUsers are stored in our List in format: `fb_user1/fb_pass1`

Now we will login with one of our fb_users:

```
public static void login(String fbUser){
    String userName = fbUser.split("/")[0]; //get UserName from fbUser
    String password = fbUser.split("/")[1]; //get Password from fbUser
    fbUsers.remove(fbUser); //remove the fbUser with which we have logged in

    //code to login
  }
```

Finally we write the fbUsers without the one we logged in back in our file:

```
public static void writeFile(){
    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName))){
      for(String fbUser : fbUsers){
        writer.write(fbUser);
        writer.newLine();
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Here is the main method:

```
private static final String fileName = "fbusers.txt";
private static final List<String> fbUsers = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args){
    readFile();
    login(fbUsers.get(0));
    writeFile();
  }
```

Hope it helps you and you can go forward with this example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I modified my code but now I'm getting this error: Index:0, Size: 0. java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source) java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)

Comment: Where you get the error? Can you show the line? Add after while loop in readFile : `System.out.printn(fbUsers.size());` is it greater than 0?

Comment: I edited my question, sysout doesn't print anything after the while loop.

Comment: Do you have this line: ``private static final List<String> fbUsers = new ArrayList<>();``?

Comment: Yup, I have it.

Comment: How many fbUsers you have in your file? The error means your ArrayList is empty. Do `System.out.println(tmp);` before `fbUsers.add(tmp);` and look how many times it prints `tmp` out.

Comment: I have 4 users in my file at the moment. For some reason it doesn't print tmp... this is the only thing I get in the console: 
Test failed!
Index: 0, Size: 0
Stack trace:
java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source) java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)

Comment: When you make a ``System.out.println("readFile")`` for the while loop does it print it out?

Comment: It only shows the error on the line where I call it, it doesn't show the error in the actual method. No, it doesn't print anything. :(

Comment: I could now ask for anything that comes to my mind that might be wrong. But thats not a so good idea. Have you a possibility to share your hole code that I can see it?

Comment: This is the whole code: https://imgur.com/a/NpDqj.
Please ignore the sysout("readfile") inside the insertFacebookDetails method, I forgot it there for some reason.

Comment: I see the problem. You must call ``readFile()`` before you call ``insertFacebookDetails(fbUsers.get(0))`` not in the method because when you call `insertFacebookDetails(fbUsers.get(0))` you try to get a element from fbUsers before the users inserted into fbUsers so by call `insertFacebookDetails(fbUsers.get(0))` the fbUsers is empty and you get your error

Comment: I can't believe it! It finally works after all this time!!! Thank you so much!!! You are the greatest!

Comment: @javaprogrammer please more than accepting his answer (@Morchul), give him  also a +1, would be nice from you. :)

Comment: Done. It's recorded but not visible since I don't have the rep.